# Update dropdown button text (without destroying <span>)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been working with this dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   company
   <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">google</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">apple</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">microsoft</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">adobe</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">other</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

When someone clicks one of the options, I want to update the "company" text to the selected option.  I was able to do this using $('#company').text('*update goes here*'); however using this destroys the  placed next to the dropdown text.  Any guidance on this one?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, not quite sure what you mean here?  All I want to do is update the dropdown button's text with the option that is selected from the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your text in a span :

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span id="cie">company</span>
   <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
```

Then update the text of the span:

```
$('#cie').html('your text');
```

Answer (score 0):

you should .append the value and not .text like this:

> $('#company').append(new value);

or you can append it to the span

```
 $('#company span').append(new value);
```

Comment: this does not appear to give the desired behavior.  after selecting an option from the dropdown, the user "company" should now read the option they have selected.  not "company" + the option they selected

Comment: so just use .text on $('#company span') but it will insert the value to the span.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you should be able to use the .html() to assign the value of the text of the button.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="company-name">company</span><span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">microsoft</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">adobe</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">other</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Added an ID to the button, and then reference it using jquery:

```
$("#company-name").html("company-name-here");
```

with company name selected as the parameter.

Comment: Updated to add a span for the company name, or you could prepend, `$('#company-name').prepend("new name here");` if you did not want to add another span and just update the buttons html.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JavaScript code:

```
$(function(){
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

  $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
  $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

});

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6600/).

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot wrap the text with an element,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjnrx3wq/)

```
function getChildText(node) {
    var text = "";
    for (var child = node.firstChild; !! child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) {
            text += child.nodeValue;
        }
    }
    return text;
}

$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(getChildText(this).trim(), "New Value"));
});
```